# C# How do I create an installation for a windows form application?

Tags: c#, installation

I have recently created a windows form application.

- I am wanting to compile everything together. All of the .dll files need to be compiled with the .exe file.
- Not only am I wanting to compile all this but I am also wanting to create an installation for my application.

I have looked on other questions on here and couldn't seem to find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You should take a look at Setup project in Visual Studio.

Comment: [All is revealed here](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow%20making%20a%20windows%20installer%20for%20c%23&es_th=1).  Also your question is essentially two.  How to merge assemblies and how to make an installer.  The latter won't care what you are installing nor how it was created

Comment: Where is the "Setup project" located at?

Comment: There's a tool called `ilmerge` that will smoosh your dlls into your exe. Creating an installer is another topic. If you have an installer, you don't probably need to bother with ilmerge.

Comment: @Micky My visual studio does not have that. Is there a way I can download it so it will get added? I have seen people try that before but every time I tried it i never had it. I have tried lots of version's of vs. VS Enterprise, VS Community, VS Express, none of them had it pre-installed.

Comment: There are a few choices there. Wix is also mentioned which is available as a stand-alone

Comment: @Blorgbeard yea that's true.

Comment: @Micky Isn't wix like a webhost or something?

Comment: @VizenDev No. Please read the links

Comment: Once you have merged your assemblies together, why not just use _ClickOnce_?  that's still part of Visual Studio to this day.

Comment: Where can i find Click Once?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 has built-in setup and deployment project.
Also you can find update for [Visual studio 2013 Update for Setup and Deployment Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: @VizenDev In Visual Studio, right-click your project, choose **Properties** then select the **Publish** tab

Comment: @Bilal I use VS 2015 Enterprise.

Comment: @Micky is do i have to link this up with a webhost?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in Visual Studio, you can open your project's Properties file in the Solution explorer. Click "Publish" on the bottom left. And then you will see a lot of stuff to choose from. Just explore the UI a bit. It's very user-friendly. Then find something called "Create Desktop Shortcut" and check that checkbox. You don't need this but it makes it easier to find your app after you install it. And then press "Publish Wizard" on the bottom right. Follow the instructions and BOOM!

You are done.

You can find the setup in the directory you specified earlier in the Publish Wizard.

If you are not using Visual Studio, **INSTALL IT**! It's beautiful (but big...)!

I am probably talking sh*t right now. If you don't understand, read this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx

Comment: Will i need to connect this to a webhost?

Comment: Nope. ----This text is useless----

Comment: I have tried just putting a path on my computer to install it so but i get the error: An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe not found.

Comment: Well now that I am getting that error from trying to publish the application, my application won't even successfully build.

Comment: If you have another question please post it as a question, not a comment. That is how I publish stuff. If it does not work for you, post a question. @VizenDev

Comment: could you link me a video on how to use it? when i look it up all the videos are showing how to do it through ftp.